# How to get historical data from a PublishSubject?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-scala, reactivex

How to get all historical data from a `PublishSubject`?

```
 val ob = PublishSubject[Int]()
 ob.subscribe(x => println("a: " + x))
 ob.onNext(1)
 ob.subscribe(x => println("b: " + x))
 ob.onNext(2)
```

It prints:

```
a: 1
a: 2
b: 2
```

You can see there is no `b: 1` printed.

If I have to use `PublishSubject` (since I need to update an observable from multi places), how can I make sure later subscribers can also get the all historical data?

Comment: Any reason you can't use a `RelaySubject`?

Comment: Because I didn't know it before, thanks ;)